# Subclasses that inherit generic interfaces

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface that ensures objects can make copies of themselves:

```
public interface Duplicable<T extends Duplicable<T>> {
    public T duplicate();
}
```

I now have

```
class X implements Duplicable<X>
```

but I also have a class Y that extends X.

This isn't a problem, until I need another generic class:

```
public class DoStuffWithDuplicable<T extends Duplicable<T>>
```

I can't use a generic version of DoStuffWithDuplicable using Y, since it does not implement `Duplicable<Y>` but `Duplicable<X>` since it inherits it from X.

So I tried

```
public class DoStuffWithDuplicable<T extends Duplicable<? super T>>
```

.. but this means later introducing an unsafe cast

```
(T) obj.duplicate()
```

in the code body.  Also the class parameters are more convoluted and the usage of the class harder to understand.  Any ideas how to get around this problem?

Comment: Can you rephrase this: "I can't use a generic version of DoStuffWithDuplicable using Y, since it does not implement Duplicable but Duplicable since it inherits it from X." ?

Comment: Yes, and you're not going to like it. Don't subclass (X, Y). Can you use composition to sever the inheritance tie?

Comment: sorry, formatting problem

Comment: No, because Y really is an X, it doesn't and can't have an X in this problem.

Comment: @phil Then you're up the creek. At best it's going to be very messy. Maybe somebody smarter than me can come up with something good.

Comment: As a note, this is exactly the sort of reason why some computer scientists say that all classes should be either `abstract` or `final`. You'll run into issues with `equals`, too; can you possibly refactor to eliminate having an instantiable `X`?

Comment: @chrylis I'm not quite that extreme, but subclassing tends to create lots of subtle problems.

Comment: @EricStein I'm not quite either, but it's a good goal and can often be met.

Comment: @phil If you'd like to post a more significant block of code on codereview, it may be possible to suss out a different design that doesn't involve extension. That's outside the scope here, though. If you do, let me know somehow and I'll take a look at it over there.

Comment: @EricStein Thanks.  The best solution I have come with so far is to not use the Duplicable interface and have another object, of class Duplicator, that is capable of providing the copies.  Seems using interfaces with Generics in class hierarchies is a bad idea -- best stick to using them for algorithms.  

(But surely there _could_ be some way to say that if the type parameter is the same as the class, it becomes the same as the class in extensions, even if this is not possible now.)

Answer (score 1):

I may not have understood your question properly, but I'll give it a go.

First of all, why do you have an interface that extends itself like that?

What you can try is this:

```
public interface Duplicable<T> {
    public T duplicate();
}
```

Then when you use another class where you want the generic parameter to be Duplicable, you do it like this:

```
public class X<T extends Duplicable<T>> {
    code...
}
```

Now when you inherit from X, any generic component in the subclasses will have to be Duplicable.

Comment: I think the "why" is quite clear: OP wants to constrain `T` to the same type as the class which implements it. Your way allows, for example, `Integer` to implement `Duplicable<String>`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: 1) But the OP's constraint doesn't constrain it. It's not possible to constrain it. 2) And the OP's constraint does not serve any type-safety purpose anyway. The interface is type safe as it is.

Comment: The bound `<T extends Duplicable<T>>` constrains `T` the same way as `Enum` constrains its type parameter: `Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`. `E` must be the enum class itself.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this in Java.

Assume you call obj.duplicate() on an object of type Y. Then the typesystem can only ensure that it will return an object of type X, since Y implements Duplicate<X>.

But you can just create a DoStuffWithDuplicable<X> and pass Y objects to it.

```
    DoStuffWithDuplicable<X> blub = new DoStuffWithDuplicable<X>();
    Y y = (Y) blub.doStuff(new Y());
```

For return values, the client of your library can just use safe casts, as he probably knows the concrete types.

An other option would be to use unsafe casts in the library and check the types manually:

```
class DoStuffWithDuplicable<T extends Duplicable<? super T>> {
    T doStuff(T obj) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T t = (T) obj.duplicate();
        if (!t.getClass().equals(obj.getClass())) 
            throw new ClassCastException("...");
        return t;
    }
}
```